# Batch tokens issue

Tags: batch-file, token

I have an issue in a simple batch command and I can't understand why the "tokens" option does not work as it should. What I am trying to do is to list the content of a folder using dir command, in a batch file, and to filter the output to show only size and names of the files. Further one I will redirect the output to a file.

For example, the default dir output executed in a folder containing 3 PDF files is the following:

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 8E72-826A

 Directory of C:\Test

16.04.2015  08:36    <DIR>          .
16.04.2015  08:36    <DIR>          ..
02.07.2014  14:35           428.974 Metrou (2).pdf
02.07.2014  14:35           428.974 Metrou (3).pdf
02.07.2014  14:35           428.974 Metrou.pdf
               3 File(s)      1.286.922 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  123.298.713.600 bytes free
```

What I am trying to obtain is the following result:

```
428.974 Metrou (2).pdf
428.974 Metrou (3).pdf
428.974 Metrou.pdf
```

To achieve this I am trying this code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=3,*" %%G IN ('dir C:\Test\*.* ^| find "pdf"') DO echo %%G >> abo.txt
```

The result is only the size, which is indeed token 3, but it should have continued with the remaining tokens how I instructed to: ,* after the 3

```
428.974 
428.974 
428.974
```

I also tried with the other option "tokens=3*" but with the same results. If I change the token to other number, 2 for example, it correctly shows the hour in our case:

```
14:35 
14:35 
14:35
```

So it seems to be reading my token option, but only the first number after =. I have not used delims since the output has only space which is read as delims by default and I also may have files with spaces in their names, like in the example above. 
Also, the code will be saved in a .bat file.

Any ideas why it ignores ,* or * in tokens?

Thanks and regards,

Iulian

Comment: `find "pdf" will find `pdf`, but not `PDF`. You should use the `/i`parameter. Anyway: why do you use `find "pdf"` instead of just `dir *.pdf`?

Comment: That's indeed a shorter way, thanks Stephan!

Comment: Stephan, actually dir *.pdf will pass to output, which will be redirected to the a file, the lines that I don't need. Example: drive C is Windows 
Number is 8E72-826A 
C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop and the disk space information from the bottom: 879.104 bytes 
123.234.299.904 bytes free

Comment: yes, that's a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

With the tokens setting as `3,*`, `%%G` will get the third token and `%%H` will get the `*` (rest of line).

The idea with `tokens` is that a *series* of environment variables are populated, starting with the one you list. From the output of `for /?` (with my italics):

> **`tokens=x,y,m-n`**
>
> Specifies which tokens from each line are to be passed to the `for` body for each iteration.
>
> This will cause *additional* variable names to be allocated.
>
> The `m-n` form is a range, specifying the `m`-th through the `n`-th tokens.
>
> If the last character in the `tokens=` string is an asterisk, then *an additional variable is allocated and receives the remaining text on the line after the last token parsed.*

Hence you will need something like (with the extra `%%H`):

```
FOR /f "tokens=3,*" %%G IN ('dir C:\Test\*.* ^| find "pdf"') DO echo %%G %%H >> abo.txt
```

---

By way of example, here's the output on my system (with irrelevant lines removed):

```
C:\pax> dir | findstr pdf
15/01/2015  09:43 AM         3,788,603 n1256_c99.pdf
03/12/2014  12:06 PM         1,692,004 n1570_c11.pdf
08/12/2014  09:48 AM         5,075,816 n3337_c++11.pdf
08/04/2015  11:11 AM         4,654,119 The Swift Programming Language.pdf

C:\pax> FOR /f "tokens=4,*" %G IN ('dir ^| findstr pdf') DO echo %G ... %H
3,788,603 ... n1256_c99.pdf
1,692,004 ... n1570_c11.pdf
5,075,816 ... n3337_c++11.pdf
4,654,119 ... The Swift Programming Language.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work independent of localization:

```
for %%i in (c:\test\*.pdf) do echo %%~zi  %%~nxi
```

although the size is not formatted with commas (which may be good or bad, depending on your needs).

see `for /?` for the modifiers `%%~zi` and `%%~nxi`

to have the ouput aligned, you can use a slight modification:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  set "size=%%~zi          "
  echo !size:~0,10! %%~nxi
)
```